# How to save information in json file without deleting previous information python

Tags: android, python, json, save, kivy

I am making an app using python and kivy that allows the user to make a new entry for their glucose readings.  Right now it saves into the json file but another new entry deletes the previous data.  How can I make it so that each entry saves separately so that I can access the information for the user's history?

**.py file**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore
from os.path import join
from os.path import exists
from kivy.compat import iteritems
from kivy.storage import AbstractStore
from json import loads, dump
from kivy.config import Config
import os
import errno



class Phone(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # make sure we aren't overriding any important functionality
        super(Phone, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    with self.canvas.before:
        Color(0, 1, 0, 1)  # green; colors range from 0-1 instead of 0-255
        self.rect = Rectangle(size=self.size, pos=self.pos)

    self.bind(size=self._update_rect, pos=self._update_rect)


    if not os.path.exists('hello.json'):
        with open('hello.json', 'wt') as inFile:
            inFile.write("")

    else:
        with open('hello.json') as inFile:
            try:
                data = Phone.load(self)
            except KeyError:
                data = []

def _update_rect(self, instance, value):
    self.rect.pos = instance.pos
    self.rect.size = instance.size

def product(self, instance):
    self.result.text = str(float(self.w.text) * 703/ (float(self.h.text) * float(self.h.text)))

def save(self):
    store = JsonStore('hello.json')
    name = self.n.text
    gender = self.g.text
    dtype = self.t.text
    height = self.h.text
    weight = self.w.text
    bmi = self.result.text
    medications = self.m.text
    insulin = self.ti.text
    store.put('profile', name=name, gender=gender, dtype=dtype, height=height, weight=weight, bmi=bmi, medications=medications, insulin=insulin)


def save_entry(self):
    time = self.gt.text
    glucose = self.gr.text
    carbs = self.c.text
    medications_taken = self.mt.text
    store.put('entry', time=time, glucose=glucose, carbs=carbs, medications_taken=medications_taken)



def load(self):
    store = JsonStore('hello.json')
    profile = store.get('profile')
    self.n.text = profile['name']
    self.g.text = profile['gender']
    self.t.text = profile['dtype']
    self.h.text = profile['height']
    self.w.text = profile['weight']
    self.result.text = profile['bmi']
    self.m.text = profile['medications']
    self.ti.text = profile['insulin']






presentation = Builder.load_file("main.kv")

class PhoneApp(App):
    def build(self):
        store = JsonStore('hello.json')

        return Phone()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    PhoneApp().run()
```

Comment: load the json, decode to a native structure, make any necessary changes to that structure, then re-encode to json and save a fresh copy.

Comment: @MarcB how do I decode to a native structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use some small json database like [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tinydb) to keep it clean. Example usage:

```
from tinydb import TinyDB, Query

db = TinyDB('./db.json')
User = Query()
db.insert({'name': 'John', 'age': 22})
result = db.search(User.name == 'John')
print result
```

Comment: @jilgeza I have never used a database before but your example is using data that you have present and not from the user.  Ideally I would like to put each entry in an array and call the spot in the array to use the information

Comment: @Azaro This is just an example, follow the documentation to achieve your goal. Instead of user dict (name and age), put dict with your data, and execute insert function.

Comment: @jilgeza I have gotten it and it works fine, but how would I call say the first set of entries?

Comment: @Azaro `result` is a list. First set will be (probably) `result[0]`, while last will be `result[-1]`.

Comment: @jilgeza after trying this I get the IndexError: index out of range  and this is the same for result[1]

Comment: Then analyse the result and check if your search query was correct.

Comment: @jilgeza I am trying to print the first entry for time. This is my code so far and it is giving me the wrong result.  `db = TinyDB('entry.json')
        User = Query()
        db.insert({'time': time, 'glucose': glucose, 'carbs': carbs, 'medications_taken': medications_taken})
        result = db.search(Query()['time'] == time)
        print result[1]`

Comment: @Azaro It throws error, because you are trying to read second query result, while there is only one record for given `time` (or even zero).  If you want to query all records, then use `result = db.search(Query().time != 0)` or similar. Maybe there is shorter notation for it, but I haven't found any.

Comment: @jilgeza doing this prints all of the information.  I am trying to print just the information for one specific key so that I can use it